# Translate operations on native types to Math.NET Numerics

Tags: f#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

In my effort to shift from using native F# types to [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) types an example would be most helpful.

How would the following be expressed as an operation on [DenseMatrix](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex32/DenseMatrix.htm) or [DenseVector](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseVector.htm) types? I've played around with the snippet below to try and express all containers as Math.NET types but kept getting a variety of errors.

```
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open MathNet.Numerics.Random
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics

let Tsize = 10
let Tsamps = 5

let expLL (arr : float []) = 
    arr |> Array.average

let arrL = Array.init Tsamps ( 
              fun i -> 
                 [| 
                     for i in 1 .. Tsize do 
                        yield Exponential.Sample(1.)
                 |] |> expLL 
           )
```

In addition, whats the quickest way to convert a `float []` or a `float [] []` to a `DenseMatrix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is anything about your sample that needs to be done differently - Math.NET provides nice functionality for doing linear algebra, but you're not really doing any matrix or vector calculations here, so basic arrays work just fine. If you wanted to turn the result into a vector, I'd probably write something like this (with minor tweak to avoid too long lines):

```
let sample () = Array.init Tsize (fun _ -> Exponential.Sample(1.0)) |> expLL    
let vecL = vector [ for i in 1 .. Tsamps -> sample() ]
```

As for turning data into matrices, there is a `matrix` function:

```
let nested = [ [1.0; 2.0; 3.0]; [4.0; 5.0; 6.0] ]
let m = matrix nested
```

Comment: The expLL function here is trivial but actually that is where most of my linear algebra is likely to be. So for that I need it to accept matrix object/s. But I think I see it now.